# How to implement container pattern in application built with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

This [article](https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005#.y33hen85g) describes a container approach for react.js applications.
How can I use this for applications built with react-router considering folders structure and components hierarchy?

Thank you!

Comment: can you give more details in your question? Consider adding a code snippet with what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @AlanSouza, i want to use containers with pages. 
For every page i have container which just pass data for page by props.
AboutPageContainer => AboutPage
In my react-router config i have 
<Route path="about" component={AboutPageController}  />
What's names of components people use for "Page" components? What folder structure i should to use? Thank you!